# How do I open a dialog page programmatically with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to open a dialog in jQuery mobile when a user clicks a button, but it doesn't seem to be working, I have a jsfiddle with the code: http://jsfiddle.net/4BBzB/

I'm using:

```
$('#get_places').click(function () {
    $.mobile.changePage("#location_popup", {
        transition: "pop",
        role: "dialog",
        reverse: false
    });
});
```

Comment: Try changing #locationn_popup with 'location_popup'

Answer (score 0):

You have malformed HTML. Change

```
 <div id="map-canvas" />
```

with

```
 <div id="map-canvas" ></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SHgYC/